# execute dashDB jobs from Workload Scheduler

Tags: jdbc, ibm-cloud, dashdb, workload-scheduler

I have created some stored procedures on my dashDB instance on Bluemix, to manipulate data in tables in the same instance.

I can run these from Data Studio and they work as intended.

Next, I created a process in Workflow Scheduler, which I provisions as a service in the same app, where the dashDB is also a service.

While creating the job step in the process, I noticed a message in the dialog window. I have attached a screen shot here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI2b7.jpg

When I did try to run the process step from Workflow Scheduler, the process failed with a JDBC not found error.

I do realize that the Workflow agent I'm using is hosted on Bluemix, so I am puzzled how I can install the JDBC client there.

Should I be setting up an agent on a local machine outside of bluemix, in a hybrid mode?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are 2 possibilities:

1. Open a ticket to ask for a dedicated cloud agent and then download
   the JDBC driver on the agent.
2. Download and install an agent on a VM or on-prem.

Comment: Yes. requested #1. For #2, my laptop is running windows 10, which is not supported for installation of agent. I might try an older machine if I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the incorrect value for "JDBC jar class path" the correct value is /home/wauser/utils/

I'm not sure why it is required that we put enter this but I was able to get the connection to dashDB working with this change.

JDBC jar class path: /home/wauser/utils/